# Ability to generate a list of 3-digit numbers from a pool of digits in Wolfram?

Tags: wolfram-alpha

I am attempting to generate a list of all possible 3-digit numbers that can be made by the numbers 1, 3, 5, 6, 7 and 9. I believe Wolfram should have the ability to give me a list, however, I am not too sure as to what to type. Can anyone help me?

Note: I don't just need the number of 3-digit numbers that *can* be made, as a combination formula can easily give me the answer to the former. Thanks!

Also no repeated digits please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** Okay, now that I'm not trying to type this on a phone keyboard where I can't see the whole thing at once,

```
Map[Fold[(#1*10+#2)&, 0, #]&, 
    Tuples[{1,3,5,6,7,9},3]]
```

Trying it on WolframAlpha [appears to work](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Map%5BFold%5B(%231*10%2B%232)%26,%200,%20%23%5D%26,%20Tuples%5B%7B1,3,5,6,7,9%7D,3%5D%5D).

***UPDATE***

Without repeated digits:

```
Map[Fold[(#1*10+#2)&, 0, #]&, 
    Permutations[{1,3,5,6,7,9},{3}]]
```

WolframAlpha [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Map%5BFold%5B(%231*10%2B%232)%26,%200,%20%23%5D%26,%20Permutations%5B%7B1,3,5,6,7,9%7D,%7B3%7D%5D%5D)

Comment: Uh, thanks, but I only want each digit to only appear once.

Comment: Updated to avoid repeated digits

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want them to be unique, that is, you don't want results like $(9,9,9)$.

```
 numbers = {1,3,5,6,7,9}; 
 result = Permutations[numbers, {3}]
```

Then you can do

```
    Length[result]
```

and see there are 120 of them.

**Note:** that this question is better suited for the Mathematica Stack Exchange, but they'd want to see your code / attempts.

Comment: I copy/pasted the top statement in, but WA doesn't understand my query. Can you please link your attempt?

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Permutations%5B%7B1,3,5,6,7,9%7D,+%7B3%7D%5D. You still haven't answered regarding unique 3 numbers or repeats allowed. Also, I posted Mathematica code.